# Choosing a gcc compiler on a Linux machine for compilation with "make"

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, mpi

I encountered the following error message on a Linux machine while attempting to compile a program with the command "make":

`` build/chem/rdm.o: In function `RDM::get_2rdm_slow(std::vector<Det, std::allocator<Det> > const&, std::vector<double
, std::allocator<double> > const&, Integrals const&)':
rdm.cc:(.text+0x37d2): undefined reference to `Timer::checkpoint(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<
char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' ``

I think the compiler I am using, gcc/6.5.0, is the wrong version, but I am not completely sure that this is the issue. Does anyone have an idea of what could be going on?
[Makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUyUO.png)

Comment: This a linking error, not a compilation one. Check the libraries you link against and their order in the command line. Adding the result of `make VERBOSE=1` into the question might also be useful.

Comment: Why do you think this is a compiler issue rather than a problem with the makefiles or the code? Not much help we can give you based on this very limited info. We would need to see the code and/or the makefiles.

Comment: For C++ code, you need to compile with g++, not gcc.

Comment: I just posted the first part of the Makefile (see blue link in question).